# PySpark RDD filter error from string to integer

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, integer, rdd

I have an RDD called `bank_rdd` which has been imported from a CSV file.

First I have split each line separated by a comma into a list

```
bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
```

The header titles are:

```
accountNumber, personFname, personLname, balance
```

I then removed the header

```
header = bank_rdd1.first()
bank_rdd1 = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda row: row != header)
```

All of the data in the CSV file is in format string. Sample data for the first two records as follows:

```
[('"1"','"John"','"Smith"','"01100"'),('"2"','"Jane"','"Doe"','"0500"')]
```

When I run the following code:

```
bank_rdd1_example = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda x: x[3] == '"01100"')
bank_rdd1_example.count()
```

I get a value of 1 which is correct because there is only one row in the dataset with a value of "01100".

When I run the following code I get an error:

```
bank_rdd1_example2 = bank_rdd1.filter(lambda x: int(x[3]) == 1100)
bank_rdd1_example2.count()
```

Basically I want this code to also return 1, but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how can you cast `"1100"` to the integer type? you should replace first.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not too good at Python. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You should find more documentation or the usage of map, lambda function for python. There are plenty of documents.

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda l: l.replace('"','').split(','))
print(rdd2.collect())

rdd3 = rdd2.filter(lambda x: int(x[3]) == 1100)
print(rdd3.collect())

[['1', 'John', 'Smith', '01100'], ['2', 'Jane', 'Doe', '0500']]
[['1', 'John', 'Smith', '01100']]
```